# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties]

Tags: java, spring

I deleted the application.properties file and included the application.yml instead of it. Suddenly, I started to get the following *FileNotFoundException* error;

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.monytyz.billing.BillingApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:252) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:751) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:569) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
```

[image]

I thought this will work naturally and I won't need any configuration for this. What's the issue here?

Comment: could you provide `BillingApplication` flie source?

Comment: Do you have dependency to https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/src/master/

Comment: @mirzak No I dont have such

Comment: @m.antkowicz There is only the main method in the code.

Comment: Just to make sure it works can you add application.properties file and try it out 

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-yaml-vs-properties

Comment: May be check if you are using `@PropertySource` somewhere in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the Spring boot. From the minimal configuration, it should automatically support application. properties or application.yml files. The error points to the old .properties file. Either check your pom or gradle file to not point on a specific config file or clean the target folder and rebuild the project.